# How can I determine the installed edition of Windows XP if the OS does not boot up?

Tags: windows-xp, boot, windows-edition

I have a drive that I cannot boot, but it has an installation of Windows XP on it.  I need to know what type of XP it has, and MS's solution (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310104) presupposes I can load the OS.  Is there a folder or file I can look at that might give me a clue as to the flavor of XP (Home, Pro, MCE, etc) I need to use for a recovery installation? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are able to boot to the command prompt you can type in:

```
type c:\windows\system32\prodspec.ini
```

and it should show you what version of XP you have installed.  Similar to something like this:

```
;
;Note to user: DO NOT ALTER OR DELETE THIS FILE.
;
[SMS Inventory Identification]
Version=1.0

[Product Specification]
Product=Windows XP Professional

Version=5.0
Localization=English
ServicePackNumber=0
BitVersion=40
[Version]
DriverVer=07/01/2001,5.1.2600.0
```

Comment: This helped once I booted from CD and got into the recovery panel

Comment: What if I have no such file on my XP partition? Is there any different way?

Answer (score 3):

If you have **MSTSC.EXE** (Remote Desktop Connection) anywhere, then it's Windows XP **Professional**. If you have **ehshell.exe** (the Media Center Shell) anywhere, it's Windows XP **MCE**. Otherwise, it's XP **Home**.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need the (exact) same version of recovery/repair CD if your only goal is to fix the boot files. The files are the same any flavour of Windows XP

In case you want to fix your boot files have a look at this TechRepublic article:
[**10 things you can do when Windows XP won't boot**](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6031733.html?tag=nl.e138)

Answer (score 1):

After some tinkering, I found that when I booted to a WinXP (MCE) CD, when I got to the prompt to install the OS / format the drive, it told me the version of XP that was previously installed on the HDD. Thanks for the help all.

Answer (score -4):

Start -> Control Panel -> System

Under the General tab.

The computer I'm on now says:

```
Microsoft Windows XP
Professional
Version 2002
Service Pack 3
```

Comment: He cannot boot the OS. How can he go to the Control Panel?

Comment: not applicable since the disk doesn't boot.