# how can I determine the windows version without booting?

Tags: windows, repair, windows-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I determine the installed edition of Windows XP if the OS does not boot up?](https://superuser.com/questions/44752/how-can-i-determine-the-installed-edition-of-windows-xp-if-the-os-does-not-boot-u)

I'm repairing a windows installation for someone, where it doesn't boot anymore.

However they don't have a clue about which version they were running and I don't either.

How can I determine the windows version, by just looking at the files alone(from a bootcd)

**EDIT:**

I've noticed an documents and settings folder so it's safe to assume it's XP.
How can I determine which service packs have been installed? (and how can I see if it is professional or home?)

Comment: @Sathya - I disagree, the person asking that question knows its XP where *reiner* is assuming it is XP. The question is similar but not an exact duplicate. I do however agree that the answers provided may lead this user in the right direction to solving their own problem.

Comment: @sathya @ricbax : That answer helped me a lot! It has all the details I needed! Thanks   I actually searched superuser fora similar question but couldn't find one... my apologies

Comment: @sathya @ricbax: should I delete this question?

Comment: Don't delete it, we can use this as a reference for others. Question will be close as Dupe.