# How can I determine what version of Windows in the windows.old folder?

Tags: windows, version

I would like to know if there are any files or directory structures that will tell me what was the previous version of Windows that created the `windows.old` folder.

Comment: Related (but too narrow): [How can I determine the installed edition of Windows XP if the OS does not boot up?](http://superuser.com/questions/44752/how-can-i-determine-the-installed-edition-of-windows-xp-if-the-os-does-not-boot)

Comment: Windows Vista and Windows 7 and Windows 8 all use identical file structures.  The contents of Windows.old is only the contents of the profile directories.

Comment: Useful if you grab an old hard drive and want to know the OS installed on it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In C:\windows.old\system32, open the properties for any system file, like 'ntoskrnl.exe'. 
On the Details tab, you see the Product Version:

- 10.0 = Windows 10
- 6.3 = Windows 8.1
- 6.2 = Windows 8
- 6.1 = Windows 7
- 6.0 = Windows Vista
- 5.2 = Windows Server 2003
- 5.1 = Windows XP
- 5.0 = Windows 2000
- 4.0 = Windows NT 4

It gets a bit trickier if you need to know whether it was a home,pro, enterprise or server version.

Comment: I just wanted to know if the previous installation was vista or 7. I think that should do it. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 5):

Open the "\Windows.old\system32\license.rtf" file in a text editor and look at the 2nd title row, it will tell you the exact Windows edition, as was initially installed.
I verified this method on Windows Vista Business, Win7 Ultimate and Win8.1 Pro.

Comment: Sadly with Windows 10 it just says `WINDOWS OPERATING SYSTEM`

Comment: On a customer's computer, `Windows.old\system32\license.rtf` didn't exist, but I did a search for `license.rtf` and found a few in subdirectories.